# Trying to calculate Kurtosis using my own function, but my output is "numeric(0)"

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate Kurtosis using my own function, but my output is "numeric(0)". I understand this has something to do with the indexing system in R.

Here is my code:

```
function(data.new)
{

  data <- as.matrix(data.new)
  n <- nrow(data.new)

  for (i in 1:50) { kurtosis<-((1/n)*((sum((data[i,]-mean(data)))/sd(data)))) }
  a <- print(kurtosis)
  a
}
```

Here is my output:

> kurt(state.x77[,"Frost"])
>   numeric(0)

I am trying to get a single value output for kurtosis of a column of data.

Comment: It's helpful if you share some data as well. Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn about minimal reproducible examples

Comment: Change the line `n <- nrow(data)`

Comment: Thank you. Sorted it out immediatly.

Comment: Use `debug(kurt)` Read the help page  of `debug()`

Comment: `nrow(data.new)` gives `NULL` as result. Probabply you want `kurt <- function(x) mean(((x-mean(x))/sd(x))^4)` Formula for kurtosis from https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%B6lbung_(Statistik)