# I want to create a function in R tha return to me the skewness and the kurtosis simultaneously from the vector y

Tags: r

I want to create a function in R that return to me the skewness and the kurtosis simultaneously from the vector y:

```
set.seed(1112);

y <- x <- 11 + sqrt(12) * rnorm(5000);

y[sample(x = 5000, size = 200, replace = F)] <- NaN;
```

Comment: function for [skewness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861339/creating-a-function-to-calculate-the-skewness-of-a-given-vector) and [kurtosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292643/trying-to-calculate-kurtosis-using-my-own-function-but-my-output-is-numeric0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions from `DescTools` to create a function to return both.

```
kurt_skew <- function(x){
  skewness <- DescTools::Skew(y, na.rm=TRUE)
  kurt <- DescTools::Kurt(y, na.rm=TRUE)
  return(list(skewness = skewness, kurt = kurt))
}

kurt_skew(y)

#$skewness
#[1] -0.02903336

#$kurt
#[1] -0.01281097
```